# How to get Email of friend using google+ api?

Tags: c#, google-plus

Im creating an application to login in Google+ and get friends emails.
Im authenticating succesfully and get token back , but when i fetch friends list , the user class of any single friends has emails=null...

here is the code (After already signed in and get authenticator class):

```
// Generated libraries for Google APIs
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Plus.v1;
using Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data;
// For OAuth2
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

//....code for authentication skipped ....


//...callback from json (authentication success)

PlusService ps = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
  Authenticator = authenticator
});

PeopleFeed peopleFeed = ps.People.List("me", PeopleResource.CollectionEnum.Visible).Fetch();

//After that when i inspect peopleFeed[0].Emails <--- this is null..
```

any help?

Answer (score 6):

The Google+ API only returns public information. So even if **you** are permitted to see a person's email address, it does not necessarily mean that the information is public and that it will be returned.

Furthermore, the documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list only guarantees that the list of people returned will contain the person's

- id
- displayName
- image
- url

and that to get other information about the person, you will need to do a `people.get` against that ID. But, again, note that you may still not get their email if that information isn't public.

Comment: I checked the people.get against the ID and it turned out that the email ids are not public.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [Contacts v3 API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to get friend's email addresses. You can cross map this to Google+ contacts by looking at the `gContact:website` element for the contact that comes back in the XML response:

```
<gContact:website href='http://www.google.com/profiles/1234567890' rel='profile'/>
```

In that element's href attribute, 1234567890 is the person identifier that would match the `id` field of the relevant [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) from [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) of the Google+ API.

Note that the profile link is not guaranteed to come back for a contact entry. This occurs when the contact has not been linked to a Google+ profile.

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be that it's a rights management issue. I remember when I asked for my Google API key, I had to mention what information I want to get.

Could you check your API key settings in the Google Developer network and see if you need to enable it there?